# How to get the top offset of an element in an Ember project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I try to get the offset position of an element using JQuery

```
Ember.$('section:nth-child(2)').offset().top
```

But this code returns the wrong value. The problem comes from Ember that add some Div wrapper around my elements.

My DOM structure look like this :

```
Html > Body > 
    Div[class='ember-view'] > Div[class='ember-view'] > 
        Div[class='Container'] > Div[class='row']
           Section
           Section
           ...
```

But this Ember Div are not count into parentNode. 
Any solution?

Edit - This is the CSS code apply on section :

```
section {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,     main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

And the JS code :

```
__init : function() {
Ember.$('#expand-btn').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Ember.$('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
  Ember.$('.nav-link:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');

  var elem = Ember.$('.container>#main>section:nth-child(2)')[0];
  //Return 509, not 480
  console.log(elem.getBoundingClientRect().top - elem.scrollTop);

  Ember.$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : Ember.$('section:nth-child(2)').offset().top}, 750);
});

}.on('didInsertElement')
```

didInsertElement ensures that the code is execute after DOM was loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution. it's more a trick than a solution. I must take care of the navbar offset which is 56px. So i subtract the nabber height to the offset.
i think i will contact Materializecss developpers to find a better way with them

Answer (score 1):

There's a wonderful DOM Element method called [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) which returns an object that contains all offsets from the top-left corner of the viewport.

So just doing:

```
Ember.$('section:nth-child(2)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Should get you covered.

Comment: i try your method. It return the same result as offset() or position(). My screen size is 480 and it return 509px

Comment: Then it's possible that the element you're querying is contained in another element with a vertical scroll, or the entire document has a scroll. In that case you'll also have to add the `scrollTop` of the aforementioned (see in the docs I linked to).

Comment: Same result when i make getBoundingClientRect().top - scollTop.

Comment: I've find the problem, I uses Materializecss as CSS framework. When i delete their navbar, all work fine. So navbar is the problem. It use a mix of relative and fixed positioning.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherent to that structure that would change the value of `offset()`. divs are unstyled by default and `offset` calculates relative to the document, not parent elements.

If the `offset` changes it's because of your styling or because `offset` is called  when the page is in an incomplete state (like if say images hasn't finished loading yet).

Please include a more complete example if you want a more precise answer, preferably with where you call `Ember.$('section:nth-child(2)').offset().top` and the styling.